# Mysql : select count when id have multiple same value

Tags: mysql, count

```
+------+---------+
| id   | object  |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    1    |
| 1    |    2    |
| 1    |    3    |
| 1    |    4    |
| 2    |    3    |
| 2    |    4    |
| 3    |    5    |
| 3    |    3    |
| 3    |    4    |
+------+---------+
```

i want to select count id where have a same value, so the result be, id 1 have 4 same value, id 2 have 2 same value, id 3 have 3 same value .

```
+------+
| id   | 
+------+
| 4    |  
| 2    |   
| 3    |  
+------+
```

thanks for help, master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT id, COUNT(object) FROM tablename GROUP BY id`

Comment: ok , i just confused that the 2 answer of my question all is right . :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `test` GROUP BY id
```